# Update Table only works once in datagridview (c#)

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have a datagridview in which I have made cells editable. Once the user has entered any text, they hit the "UPDATE" button, it updates the database.

The problem is whenever I open the application, it does update only for the first time. When I try to make more modification and click "UPDATE" button, it fails to update database. Here is my code. Please suggest any solution

```
private void Form1_Load_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        con.Open();
        sda = new SqlDataAdapter("Select * from Name", con);
        ds = new System.Data.DataSet();
        sda.Fill(ds);
        dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
    }


private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {           

        scb = new SqlCommandBuilder(sda);
        sda.Update(ds);

    }
```

Comment: what is the value of `scb` in the following ` scb = new SqlCommandBuilder(sda);` use the debugger.. also where are you rebinding the dataGridView1.DataSource to ds.Tables[0] in your button click.. you need to null the data source and reassign it to the new ds ..

Comment: if you want to keep a copy of the data and display the data on the gridview once edited.. you need to add an event to the `RowEdting` if available on the DataGridView, also you can keep a copy of the data in a Session variable after you first load it like the following 
`DataTable dt = Session["initialdata"] = ds.Tables[0] as DataTable` then when you set up the datagridview to allow inline editing you can capture and rebind etc.. but updating to the database you will need to write separate code.. it's not that difficult where is your update statement you can't do an update on select * from

Comment: I looked at some youtube tutorials and some blogs and it worked this way.

Comment: what does it worked this way mean.. worked the way that you are doing it or not working the way that you are doing it..?

Comment: Yes, I implemented the logic from some tutorial. for example - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_i4mYXSaD4w

Comment: Also, I don't know how true this explanation is - http://stackoverflow.com/a/31213722/4971115

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, there is nothing wrong with the code I mentioned. Instead there was some another section which was causing db not to be updated.

I also kept a Refresh button with this code -

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       sda = new SqlDataAdapter("Select * from Name", con);
       DataTable dt = new DataTable();
       sda.Fill(dt);
       dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
    }
```

Seems that it reverted back Update to original db content. Removing it worked successfully.

Comment: that's what I was telling you earlier James basically you needed to fill it then reassign the datasource of the dataGridView1 to `dt`