# Inserting Data Into SQL Server Database Through DataGridView Not Working In Visual Studio

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio, winforms

I'm trying to get the data in my "Jokes" table to update in SQL Server when I change the cell(s) in this DataGridView and click the "Update" button I made. I tried following along with a tutorial, but it seems to just not work. What do I need to change here to make it work? I'm not getting any errors oddly, so it must just be the way I did it or something. Thanks for any help.

This is the entire code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace TestProject1
{
    public partial class UserControl3 : UserControl
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=MSI;Initial Catalog=Jokes;Integrated Security=True;");
        SqlDataAdapter adpt;
        DataTable dt;
        DataSet ds;
        SqlCommandBuilder cmdbl;

        public UserControl3()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            ShowData();
        }

        private void fillByToolStripButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                this.jokesTableAdapter.FillBy(this.jokesDataSet.Jokes);
            }
            catch (System.Exception ex)
            {
                System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }

        private void UserControl3_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            con.Open();
            ds = new DataSet();
            adpt.Fill(ds, "Jokes");
        }

        public void ShowData()
        {
            adpt = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM Jokes", con);
            dt = new DataTable();
            adpt.Fill(dt);
            dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
        }

        private void BackGridButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Hide();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                cmdbl = new SqlCommandBuilder(adpt);
                adpt.Update(ds, "Jokes");
                MessageBox.Show("Jokes Updated");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Double check (by debugging) whether the property `builder.GetUpdateCommand().CommandText` is returning a valid update command.

If not, add the update your try-block in button1_Click to look like this

```
cmdbl = new SqlCommandBuilder(adpt);
adpt.UpdateCommand = cmdbl.GetUpdateCommand();
adpt.Update(ds, "Jokes");
MessageBox.Show("Jokes Updated");
```

I do admit that the second in line above code snippet should not be required theoretically looking at the way you instantiated the SqlCommandbuilder. But it would just be to re-affirm and also part of the reason why I suggested to check that property in Debug mode.

Comment: Now it says, "The name 'adapter' does not exist in the current context", as well as, "The name 'sqlBld' does not exist in the current context". Is it a misspelling?

Comment: oh yes, I just added sample line, didn't take care to match the variable names, my bad. Edited it now.

Comment: Odd. I'm getting this error when I try to click the update button: "Dynamic SQL generation for the UpdateCommand is not supported against a SelectCommand that does not return any key column information."

Comment: Oh nevermind I fixed it. I had to go into SSMS and add a primary key. I made the primary key "JokeID". Now I still have the main issue unfortunately. Whenever I click the "Update" button after changing one of the cells in the DataGridView, it says "Jokes Updated", but it doesn't change it in the database. When I stop and restart the form, or do a SELECT * FROM Jokes query in SQL Server, it didn't change at all.

Comment: Did you check the value of this in debug - `cmdbl.GetUpdateCommand().CommandText`

Comment: Hmm... when I debugged it, it said that adpt.UpdateCommand is null.

Comment: Oh, and by the way, I put what you gave me into button1_Click.

Comment: I just found something interesting here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31167951/updating-sql-database-from-datagridview-in-c-sharp Would you happen to know about that? Thanks.